# Delete entire dataframe rows based on condition and stack remaining rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date          Name      Grade       Hobby
01/01/2005    Albert    4           Drawing
08/04/1996    Martha    6           Horseback riding
03/03/2003    Jack      5           Singing
07/01/2001    Millie    5           Netflix
24/09/2000    Julie     7           Sleeping
...
```

I want to filter the df to only contain the rows for repeat dates, so where `df['Date'].value_counts()>=2`
And then groupby dates sorted in chronological order so that I can have something like:

```
Date          Name      Grade       Hobby
08/08/1996    Martha    6           Horseback riding
              Matt      4           Sleeping
              Paul      5           Cooking
24/09/2000    Julie     7           Sleeping
              Simone    4           Sleeping
...
```

I have tried some code, but I get stuck on the first step. I tried something like:

```
same=df['Date'].value_counts()
same=same.loc[lambda x:x >=2]
mult=same.index.to_list()

for i in df['Date']:
    if i not in mult:
        df.drop(df[df['Date'==i]].index)
```

I also tried

```
new=df.loc[df['Date'].isin(mult)]
plot=pd.pivot_table(new, index=['Date'],columns=['Name'])
```

But this only gets 1 of the rows per each repeat dates instead of all the rows with the same date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `Date` to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then filter rows in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

same=df['Date'].value_counts()
df1 = df[df['Date'].map(same) >= 2].sort_values(['Date','Grade'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Or use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for count 2 and more, what is same like duplicates:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = df[df['Date'].duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values(['Date','Grade'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I then stack df1 to get the output I described above?

Comment: @Mary - do you think duplciated Dates convert to empty strings?

Comment: Oh no, sorry, I just figured out what I was doing wrong

Comment: The code you provided worked great, thank you!

Comment: How can I sort the dates chronologically? When I try to use ```sort_values('Date', ascending=True)``` it sorts by day and not the full date. If I do ```sort_values(df.Date.dt.date, ascending=True)``` I get an error because of the duplicate values

Comment: @Mary - There is added `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)` ?

Comment: Yeah that is the problem, it sorts by date so I get the order like 01/01/2022, 01/03/2021, 03/04/2018, 03/0872010, 03/10/2016

Comment: Would it be easier to sort by ```same``` to have the dates with highest frequency at the top?

Comment: @Mary - I got it, need `sort_values(['Date','Grade'], ascending=[True, False])`

Comment: It's still not working for me, not sure why. Do you know how I can do it by ```same``` so I get the most frequent at the top?

Comment: @Mary - Are data confidental?

Comment: Yes, I can't upload the variable output. ```same``` is a pandas Series that has the dates timestamps for indexes and their frequencies as values. How can I use frequencies to sort the df1 values?

Answer (score 2):

Think this should do the job

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df_new = df[df['Date'].duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values('Date')
```